# Mac OS X 10.7.4 breaks OpenGL Profiler

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, osx-lion

I've recently discovered that when upgrading from 10.7.3 to 10.7.4 that OpenGL Profiler no longer appears to be able to hook into a program. It can launch an app fine, but no break points, traces, resources etc work.

I found this question: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3958500?start=0&tstart=0 but can't seem to figure out the soltuion the poster suggests, can someone shed some light on how to do this in xcode?

Comment: What part of the solution the poster suggests can you not figure out? He posted screen shots of exactly what you have to click on. Which one is confusing you?

Comment: Because his is a cocoa application where mine is a command line tool. They have different project settings and his solution doesn't seem applicable to my program.

Comment: same problem here with a command-line opengl program...